# When do you have to wrap callback function of a spec with Async?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-test, angular-unit-test

For some reason these two specs are passing, however the second spec is testing interpolation within the template, with async data from a service. Why is it not necessary to wrap the callback function with async?

```
describe('SaangComponent', () => {
  let component: SaangComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SaangComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SaangComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: GetSomeService, useValue: getSomeServiceMock}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SaangComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should update the h1 attribute with the title', () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();
    const expectedText = compiled.innerHTML;
    expect(expectedText).toEqual('lord');
  });
});

const getSomeServiceMock = {
  getSomeData() {
    return Observable.of({title: 'lord'});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to wrap callback function in testing block with `async` or `fakeAsync` Angular helpers if a function is expected to be asynchronous.

`getSomeServiceMock` uses `Observable.of` and is *synchronous*. This is why `async` is optional.

If the components involved in this test suit doesn't contain asynchronously loaded components, `async` in `beforeEach` is optional, too.

As a rule of thumb, all testing blocks may be wrapped with `fakeAsync`. It's faster than `async` and will let you know if it's unsuitable (when real asynchronous operations happen in a block).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 'getSomeData' is called in the component's ngOnInit lifecycle hook. If so the mock response you are using is already used when you are creating the component.